# How to mount a WiFi router on wall without using nails?

Tags: mounting, nails, routers

My landlord isn't allowing me to make holes on the wall, and my WiFi router on ground is not giving much coverage. So is there any way I can mount a WiFi router to the wall, a little bit above the ground so to increase its range?

There's a bulb holder on the wall, so I was thinking of using some strings to hang the router. Will that be ok?

Comment: Put it on top of the refrigerator.

Comment: reach from kitchen is not good in my room, so i can't put it up there. Also there's no wiring in kitchen. @Harper

Comment: yes, you can hang the router, it doesn't really care and in fact, that would give it good airflow, which could keep it cooler, which could result in a longer uptime and better performance. Command(r) adhesive hooks and large globs of poster putty are additional options.

Comment: Silly question: have you consider plugging your computer in with a cable? (of course, not applicable for cellphones...)

Comment: Thanks @dandavis i'll all "adhesive hooks" in my cart list. Hope it works with my wall surface and able to sustain the weight.

Comment: Just be aware that adhesive hooks can come with different strengths for the adhesive, and some of the stronger varieties can be *very* hard to remove (possibly doing more damage than a small screw). have you considered buying a small table or end stand, and put the router on that? maybe something with a couple shelves/drawers? Goodwill or a local thrift store will definitely have something that will work for a reasonable price.

Comment: I second the suggestion for adhesive hooks (one brand name is Command), or go with the true classic, a milk crate.

Comment: I would put (very small) holes in the wall. If you do a good job of filling them they'll never be discovered. What kind of place doesn't allow a photo frame to be hung?

Comment: WiFi Router? They'll add internet gimmicks to anything nowadays. No thanks, I'll just keep my trusty old Craftsman router, doesn't need any wifi, just keep the bits sharp.

Comment: Screw the router to a broom handle and lean the broom against the wall.

Answer (score 4):

The 3M adhesive hooks work exactly as advertised.  I had some mounted for 4 years & they came off the wall clean as a whistle. Go ahead and rig some interface from the 3M hooks to whatever will hold up the router.

**BUT**  first have someone hold the router in the intended location to verify that you actually do get improved range.

Answer (score 2):

**Mannekin?**

[image]

Now when you have a date over and she asks why you own a creepy mannekin, you will explain that it is because you could not drill holes in the wall.

Comment: Doubles as a hat rack.

Comment: obligatory:  "personnekin"  .  Tho' maybe C3PO would be a better choice.

Comment: LOL man, thats creepy

Answer (score 0):

Using string to hang the router won't hurt it, the router won't care what orientation it is in. The only consideration I would have is that the internal antenna may be designed for a flat surface, so having it hanging at an angle may not give the best reception. This may or may not impact you and there's no harm in trying.

Hanging it from a light fixture (I'm assuming that's what you mean by bulb holder) should be fine, depending on the design, the type of bulb in it and other factors there's a slight possibility you could create a fire hazard. Again depending on the design of the fixture you may be able to back a mounting screw out a bit and tie a string to it.